# java -eclipse-Resource leak: 'appContext' is never closed

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring, applicationcontext

I create a small bean class in Eclipse. It is working in NetBeans but in Eclipse it says

> Resource leak: 'appContext' is never closed.

I closed it like this `appContext.close();`
but it is not working.

//class drawingapplication

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class drawingapplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle =(Triangle) appContext.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw();    
    }
}
```

// class Triangle

```
package org.spring.javabeans;

public class Triangle {
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println("triangle drawan");
    }
}
```

//spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN""http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="org.spring.javabeans.Triangle"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: What do you mean _it is not working_? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Answer (score 1):

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is a subclass of `ConfigurableApplicationContext` which means it implements `Closable`.

`ApplicationContext` does not extend `Closeable`, so the `Closable#close()` method cannot be invoked on any reference of type `ApplicationContext`.

However, Eclipse detects that you are assigning a value of type `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` (which needs to be closed), and warns that you should close it, even though you can't through the reference type of the variable you are assigning it to.

You need to either cast the reference value or assign it to a variable of a type that does implement `Closeable`.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

You can then invoke `close()` normally

```
appContext.close();
```

Comment: now it gives NullPointerException  i do like this ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle triangle =(Triangle) appContext.getBean("triangle");
        triangle.draw(); 
        appContext.close();

Comment: @heshan That error seems completely unrelated to the question and answer. You can add any issues as an edit to your question. If all details are available, maybe then I can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.spring.javabeans ;

import  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApplication {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle= (Triangle) appContext.getBean("triangle");
    appContext.close();
    triangle.draw();



}
```

}